# Definir parámetro array con objeto en Vue error undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Tengo un componente padre y un hijo, por medio del componente padre paso un parámetro al componente hijo, mi componente hijo es un modal que mando llamar desde mi componente padre, entonces si no lo llamo mi modal me arroja un error de que los datos no han sido definidos, y ocurre porque en mi modal en las propiedades que recibe solo defini;

```
 props: {
    datos_usuario: {
        required: true,
        default: [] //Aqui
    },
 }
```

Entonces me marca error en lineas como esta donde tengo ese array y dentro un objeto:

```
 datos_usuario.user_evaluate[0].firstname
```

Err:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"
```

El 0 que me marca es en `user_evaluate['AQUI']`

Como podrá definirlo, en si los datos los muestra pero me sigue apareciendo en consola el warning de que no están definidos;

Estos son los datos que recibo:

```
0: Object
user_evaluate:[
              0: {
                 firstname: 'John',
                 lastname: 'Doe'
                 }]
```

Comment: Sinceramente no entiendo tu pregunta. Pero el objeto ``datos_usuario`` no tiene la clave ``user_evaluate`` ( que aparentemente debe ser un array ), por eso te tira error. Si vos buscas una forma de agregar esa clave, con javascript podrias destructurar el objeto y metersela, algo asi: ``datos_usuario = {...datos_usuario, user_evaluate: lePasoUnArrayDeObjetos }`` y ahora podrias (si el ``user_evaluate`` que pasaste es un array de objetos, donde cada objeto tiene la propiedad ``firstname``) acceder a  ``datos_usuario.user_evaluate[0].firstname``

Comment: Lo pude solucionar, el problema era que si se refrescaba la pagina, mi componente buscaba rapido los datos del modal, los cuales solo aparecerian despues de un click en un boton, como solo se refresco la pagina y no se dio click, el componente me reconocia como indefinidos los datos, entonces el warning me recomendaba crear un objeto/array predeterminado, vaya un avariable vacia definida firtsname: '' & lastname:'' para que aunque estuviera vacio lo reconocería como definido, y funciono solo era definir la variable aunque está este vacía